# Unity Player currentActivity Always returns null on Android Device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Unity player current activity always returns null on Android device as well

Following is my code

```
_androidPluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass(androidPluginName);
AndroidJavaClass playerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject activity = playerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
_androidPluginClass.SetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("mainActivity", activity);
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Cannot find any problem in the code. Which variable is null? How did you know that?

Comment: activity "currentActivity" is null